# Compare two times (without dates) using the Python time module

Tags: python, datetime, time, compare, utc

How could something this simple be this tricky?

I want to create two times.

Time1 is a date-unaware time of UTC 8:30pm (20:30). 
Time2 is any other time (hour, minute, second) on the planet.

Hard as I've searched, the documentation and the stackoverflow examples all use the datetime module and include creating a date with the time. I just need to compare two times and, if needed, adjust Time2 to UTC.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to know anyway that comparing date-unaware time with different timezones is not a well defined problem. Especially with DST (Daylight saving time), utc offset of a timezone may depend on the date.

Comment: @AdrienMatissart to clarify, i just want to compare two times (not dates). Time 1 is UTC 20:30. Time 2 could be any other time (datetime.now().hour for example). I would want to obviously capture the tzinfo for Time 2, but it's not clear to me on how to do that.

Comment: Again, to "adjust time2 to UTC", you need a timezone AND a date. For example 10:00 in Berlin in July is 08:00 UTC, but in December, it would be 09:00 UTC.

Comment: Some code could be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that @AdrienMatissart's comment was the clue needed to figure this simple issue out. The trick was to create a datetime object for today's date at 20:30 UTC. Then to create another datetime object for the current time. By localizing the current system time to UTC, daylight savings is accounted for and the datetime objects can be compared.

```
import pytz, datetime
UTC_TZ = pytz.utc

# use combine() to create a specific datetime in today's future
end = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(20, 30, tzinfo=UTC_TZ) )

# get the current system datetime and localize to account for daylight savings
right_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=UTC_TZ)

# then I compare
if end > right_now: 
    # some action
```